# What could cause a wireless IP device to lose internet connection after 22 minutes, like clockwork?

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming

I have an Amazon Fire TV stick plugged into a TV in my house. It is in the same room as the wireless router. A room where other devices, such as laptops, get 180 Mbps down and never have connection problems.

Every evening when using the Fire TV Stick, it drops its internet connection after EXACTLY 22 minutes and will not reestablish a connection. Whether one is streaming Netflix, HBO, or some other app, this happens.  I give up every day, and then tomorrow it works again, for 22 minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: At a guess, either unaddressed issues (bugs) in the software of the stick or perhaps DHCP lease/signal issues with the router.

Comment: Any VPN? Try to power off and unplug after 19 minutes, wait 5-10 an plug and turn on again. If it works only power off after other 19... and wait for 5-10. Then test powering off the dhcp too, always 19 + 5-10 min. Post what happens. (You have to seek if hardware software in stick or in the router)

Answer (score 0):

The actual fix for this device is to turn down the power of your wireless router.  The Fire TV stick is very sensitive and requires medium power.  I had the same issue and turning down the wifi tx power on my router solved my problem.